# ProGet upload local artifacts

Tags: maven, proget

What I am looking to do is take my local maven repo (stored in .m2/repository/) and upload all the artefacts up to a ProGet server.

I cant seem to find any documents or maven plugin even that gives me this functionality?

Can anyone help please?

Comment: If you use repository manager you usually set it up and build... all the needed artifacfts will be downloaded during the build into your repo manager...

Comment: the issue I have is that I have a locked down ProGet server that I can only access on VPN. So when I build my project it pulls down the artefacts during that build process yes. But now for that project I want to take the downloaded artefacts and upload them to a ProGet server I have admin access on. I cant do any of the replication between ProGet servers because the original server I dont and cant get admin access. If that makes sense? Which is why I want to push my local artefacts up (once only or manual process if fine doesnt need to be automatic)

Comment: @AndrewKew Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [Wagon Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/) but [its latest version](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/wagon-maven-plugin) is almost two years old and I experienced things not working with recent Maven versions.

You could use the [Exec Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html) to run a script that uploads your files.